# json decode results not working

Tags: parameters, hyperlink, hide

I'm trying to **hide page address variables**, and now working with `json` encode due that didn't manage it with rewrite rules or `md5`.

At first i get the parameters with:

```
foreach($_GET as $param_name => $param_val) {

    $pagevals .= $param_name . '=' . $param_val . '&';

}

$pagevals=substr_replace($pagevals, "", -1);

$pagevals = base64_encode( json_encode($pagevals) );
```

And when trying to decode it in target page, result with echoing pagevals is:

```
$pagevals = json_decode( base64_decode( $_GET['pagevals'] ) );

echo''.$pagevals.'';

app=MIKLU_HPPP&page=updateproducts
```

But, these parameters are not active for continuing code. There is no app or page for use in page.

Have you any idea what could be work in my method?

Answer (score 0):

After reading tens of posts about hashing, encrypting, MVC, Front Controllers, etc. As i like to do things without over engineering, i figure out this.
From start, i was trying to encode whole get string with parameter name was incorrect. Solution found with encode only the value.
As this example was from my pagination, and get the parameters dynamically for target page, i did it with following method.
Pagination has all ready encoded values for app and page, so they are first decoded to avoid encoding twice of values:

foreach($_GET as $param_name => $param_val) {

if($param_name=="app" OR $param_name=="page") {

```
$param_val=base64_decode($param_val);
```

}

$pagevals .= $param_name . '='.base64_encode($param_val).'&';

}

$pagevals=substr_replace($pagevals, "", -1);

And the pagination works like a charm. Parameters are encoded. Without adding huge amount extra classes or code for rewrite or routing things.
I see that it would be better if i add salt also along, for better security.
As i have used base64 without json in resolution code, i think, why to use json. What is the benefit of it??